# How to detect when iPhone is moving in X direction?

Tags: iphone, accelerometer

How do I detect that the iPhone is moving in a particular direction (X-axis)?  Can you show some sample code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with help of UIAccelerometer and check the movement fo phone in x-axis by:

```
 - (void)accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)aceler {
        if (sqrt(aceler.x * aceler.x) > 1.5f)
        {
                  //write your code here
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Thanks,

Madhup